# Suprema and infima of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space and $(\mu_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of measures. Let:

$$\sup_{i\in I} \mu_i : \mathcal E \to [0\, ..\infty], A \mapsto \sup_{i\in I} \mu_i(A)$$

$$\inf_{i\in I} \mu_i : \mathcal E \to [0\, ..\infty], A \mapsto \inf_{i\in I} \mu_i(A)$$

> Is $\sup_{i\in I} \mu_i $ / $\inf_{i\in I} \mu_i $ a measure? If not generally what if $I = \mathbb{N}$ and / or  we require the $\mu_i$'s to be localizable, $\sigma$-finite or finite? If not, are there other ways to define suprema and infima in the lattice of measures (satisfying some property)?

Comment: No. Consider $E=\{0,1\}$, $\mathcal E$ the power set of $E$,  $I=\{1,2\}$, $\mu_1$ puts weight $1/3$ on $\{0\}$ and weight $2/3$ on $\{1\}$, and  $\mu_2$ puts weight $2/3$ on $\{0\}$ and weight $1/3$ on $\{1\}$. The setwise maximum of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, call it $\nu$, satisfies $\nu(E)=1$ but $\nu(\{0\})=\nu(\{1\})=2/3$, so $\nu$ is *not* additive.

Comment: To get pointed in the right direction, consider the case $I=\{1,2\}$ and each $\mu_i$ a finite measure. Let $\lambda:=\mu_1+\mu_2$. By the Radon-Nikodym theorem, $\mu_i$ has a density $f_i$ with respect to $\lambda$. Define $g$ to be the pointwise maximum of $f_1$ and $f_2$, and then let $\eta$ be the measure whose density with respect to $\lambda$ is $g$; that is, $\eta(A):=\int_A g\,d\lambda$. Clearly $\eta$ is a finite measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$, and $\eta$ is the least measure dominating both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.......

Comment: ........ More precisely, if $\xi$ is another measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ such that $\xi(A)\ge\mu_i(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal E$ and $i\in I$, then $\xi(A)\ge\eta(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal E$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you! You seem to have partially answered the question I *meant* to ask: "Is the poset of measures of some property a complete lattice or a lattice with countable meets / joins?"

Comment: @JohnDawkins It seems this still works for $I = \mathbb{N}$ but not for general $I$ (there is no way to add uncountably many measures). Do you know something about the case of infima? Does it work the same way?

Comment: Supposed EDIT:  I actually don't know whether $\sigma$-finiteness is preserved by taking countable sums...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general collection $\mathcal C=\{\mu_i:i\in I\}$, first close up $\mathcal C$ under the formation of finite maxima. That is, define $\mathcal D:=\{\max(\mu_i:i\in A): A\subset I, A$ finite$\}$. Now define $\mu(A):=\sup\{\nu(A): \nu\in\mathcal D\}$ (setwise supremum). It's a straightforward exercise to show that $\mu$ is countably additive, and then that $\mu$ is the least measure dominating each measure in $\mathcal C$.

Comment: Is there a reference for this result?